# ASP.NET: Get value of literal.text after page load?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm trying to use the following code to get the text value of a literal so that I can pass it to the next page using PreviousPage, but the string is empty, I think it clears the values after the Page_Init stage.

```
Public ReadOnly Property SendText() As String
    Get
        Return literal1.Text
    End Get
End Property
```

Is there a way around this?

Im trying to access the data on the next page using:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Spacing.aspx" %> 
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    litTables.Text = PreviousPage.SendText
End Sub
```

Even better would be if I could set SendText to the HTML contents of a whole div, but the only way I see to access this is using the JavaScript document.getElementById("tables").innerHTML, but I don't see how I could incorporate that into the ReadOnly Property using Get.

I'm using Visual Studio Express For Web 2012.

Comment: Can you show a more complete example of what you're trying to do?  It sounds like you're misunderstanding some key concepts of web applications and/or the ASP.NET page lifecycle, but the terminology you're using is making it very unclear.  When/how are you trying to access this property?

Comment: I've added more info, I'm basically trying to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx "Getting Public Property Values From the Source Page".

Comment: This looks like a very odd way to pass information from one page context to another.  What's the actual information being passed?  Seems like it would make more sense to store it in something like `Session` in this scenario.  Or perhaps include it on the query string in the link to the second page.  Normally a page can post data to another page in a form, but WebForms kind of broke HTML forms in that regard.

Comment: It sounds like you're passing a group of tables across pages? Could you use a class to generate the tables on each page as you need to based on something like a cookie value?

Comment: It's quite a lot of data on a multi user site so I don't want it stored anywhere, I think I'll just try and use POST as suggested below, not sure if you can do this using a hyperlink though?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the way you would pass data between pages in an ASP.NET application. The recommended way would be to POST the data or pass it via the URL.

Comment: How would I go about using POST? I've looked it up but don't see how I can transfer the data into a form? It's to big to pass via the URL by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The data I need to transfer is:

```
<div id="tables">
        <asp:Literal ID="lit1" runat="server" ValidateRequestMode="Disabled"></asp:Literal>&nbsp;
        <asp:Literal ID="lit2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>&nbsp;
        <asp:Literal ID="lit3" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
```